# How to create bootable debian usb drive from an existing linux partition?

Tags: debian, boot, usb

I've been using linux (ubuntu, debian, and salix) for a few years but have never been able to create a bootable usb drive from within linux. I've always had to use pendrivelinux which is a downloadable .exe I would like to not use windows at all anymore but have not found a guide for this particular problem that I have been able to get working.

Can someone provide step by step instructions/links for creating a debian boot usb drive?

Answer (score 4):

Is not that hard, all you need is a USB device with enough space (4 GB or more) and the ISO image of Debian.

1. Format your USB device with FAT32 file system. The easiest way is to use `GParted`.
2. Use `dd` as root to copy the ISO image to your USB device.

   `dd if=/path/to/your/debianxxx.iso of=/dev/sdx`

`sdx` is the name of your USB device in the system, e.g. `sdb`, `sdc`, etc.

**WARNING:** Make sure you use the correct name for your device because `dd` will destroy all data on that device.

Now reboot your PC and boot from the USB.

Comment: Formatting is unnecessary. When you write with dd you're copying from the iso which is an image of a block device that contains its own ISO9660 filesystem to the block device of the target drive. If you make a filesystem on the target drive before this, it'll just be overwritten. Second, I suggest to add the "bs" argument and write more than the default 512 bytes at a time. Last, I would recommend appending && sync to the command, because it's possible for dd to return before the write finishes. So it should become `dd if=/path/to/your/debianxxx.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1M && sync`

Comment: @TylerChambers Thanks for the tips. I wasn't aware of those options, I'll try them out before updating my answer, which might take some time.

Comment: An important thing to note is that the output path needs to be the name of the _device_, not a particular partition on the device (e.g. `of=/dev/sdx` rather than `of=/dev/sdx1`). If you write to a partition then you'll get a boot error complaining that the partition table is invalid.

Comment: I would suggest adding `status` to the dd command, to monitor progress. Use as below: `dd if=/path/to/your/debianxxx.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use a tool with a final checkpoint. `dd` is a powerful tool, but it does what you tell it to do without questions, so if you point to the wrong device by mistake, you may overwrite valuable data.

[Tools with a final checkpoint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927268/cant-boot-from-usb-drive-after-copying-iso-with-dd/927299#927299)

- **Startup Disk Creator** (bundled in Ubuntu)
- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility  # in Debian and Ubuntu
  ```
- [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  - In Ubuntu

    If you run standard Ubuntu *live*, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

    ```
    sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
    ```
  - [In Debian you can also use the Ubuntu PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian)

    If you don't want to use a PPA (to install mkusb), or if you are running another linux distro, not based on Debian or Ubuntu, you can
  - [Install mkusb from a tarball](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui/tarball)
  - [Install mkusb-min if you want it simple](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/min)

Answer (score -1):

Below is how to install from a USB installer and into a drive on USB drive.

This is useful knowledge, and environmentally friendly. For anyone fond of linux, installing on USB gives a feeling of technology revolution. This is why I think we can do an exception an give a recipe on stack overflow. Instead of buying a laptop, and instead of changing computer often to safeguard unsaved data, one can have all the essential data on a robust portable external usb drive. And it is still super fast. And it is simpler than double boot. Double boot changes often, with windows that override it, or for example recently Windows and the BIOS added a PIN step during boot time.

I did it with success and I will share below the knowledge. As a question I ask you if you have suggestions of improvements. This recipe was made for Debian Buster 10 in May 2020.

Flash USB has a limited life time and running linux on flash will consume the life fast. Solid state discs are very robust with very many years of life, and can be used via USB. The USB3, especailly the USB3.1, are super fast. And the socket on the computer is blue. If you use USB2, it can take several days to install debian.

```
You need to make a linux debian installer on a flash usb (cheap). Note, any flash usb that you use must be formatted fat32 since it is more copmatible with the BIOS.
```

sudo fdisk -l located the USB, and make sure it is on /dev/sdb dd if=PATH_TO_ISO_FILE of=/dev/sdb bs=4M sync you must write sdb and not sdb + a number

```
First you need under a linux installation to clear the drive with 0s.
```

This is needed so that the debian installer will create a GPT partition table instead of reusing the MBR one that is inferior. to clear the disc: sudo fdisk -l sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1

```
(optional) update the bios It helps to make USB 3 work better. This can damage your computer if you do not install the right file. You will need the exact BIOS file from your manufacturer's website. In my case, the manufacturer ASUS had only one general file and not the one exactly for my motherboard. But I found the file on an online public websites for PC drivers. I usually never trust those sites, but the file worked.
```

Then you copy the bios file on a flash usb format fat32, you wil find somewhere in the bios one can update it.

```
Now you will install debian on the solide state drive Connect the flash usb installer, and the SSD drive on 2 USB sockets. USB 3 sockets are blue. In the bios, deactivate fast boot and secure boot. find a way to boot on the usb installer, such as by reordering the boot sequence with + and -.

start the usb installer in graphical expert mode. set http as mirror activate the backports during the installation (you will need later a newer kernel for booting on USB 3) you must pick a manual partioning mode and set an logical efi partition 300MB, a logical swap partition of a few GB, and all the rest as primary mounted on slash not slash home as given sometimes you must not install grub during the installation, because it would install with the efi of your non-usb hard disc, and on your motherboard's flash.

Now you will install grub in removable mode complete the installation and reboot restart the installer in expert rescue mode if you cannot boot on the installer, try again, unplugging the usb socks, and stopping the power. I saw it disappear and come back In the rescue mode, the end you should mount the disc. You msut mount the efi that it autodetects. And you need to guess which /dev/sdcX has your debian stuff. It is probably /dev/sdc3 if you made 3 partitions as said above.
```

the installer has done all the hard stuff for you. It has mounted the efi partition on the usb disc from /dev/sdc1 to /boot/efi, This is why I recommend using the rescue mode.

Now you should update the linux kernel. Because booting on USB 3 works much better wit ha new kernel. The backported kernel is 100% safe and compatible, it is not an unstable one. apt update apt-cache show linux-image-amd64 -t buster-backports you will see several versions. THe one on stable, and the one on backports apt-get install linux-image-amd64 -t buster-backports

6.b You must correct fstab cat /etc/fstab you will see that the EFI UUI is incorrect

here you can see the destination of a certain UUID: ls -l /dev/disc/by-uui/7927-04C9 you need to change s othat it points to the EFI partition on the USB, and not the on on the non-usb disc. sudo nano /etc/fstab CTRL +X to save and exit check also that /boot/efi points to the usb and not to the hard disc use sudo fdisk -l to know which /dev/ZZZ refers to.

the rescue mode has already mounted the root on the usb. HEnce you do not need a chroot.

```
Now the grub installer will map to that new kernel grub-install --removable update-grub read the output if there are errors then you can leave the rescue mode
```

optional: there is way to install grub for secure boot with --uefi-secure-boot available if you install grub-efi-amd64-signed via apt. But I do not recommend it. I think it is simpler to remove secure boot in the BIOS.

```
Now boot on the usb disc, and do some additional installation of firmwares
```

In a first try, I did not use the smart trick above. I had installed already grub, and my /etc/fstab was pointing to a wrong stuff in /dev/disc/by/uuid/. I had to use chroot on the usb partition after mounting proc, sys, dev (see details at the bottom of this post). And it worked. An alternative is to use --boot-directory, --efi-directory but I do not think it could fix my wrong label in /etc/fstab. But afterwards, when I installed on another USB SSD drive, I prefered to use the rescue mode of the installer. It is much simpler wihtout hacks.

You should also install the prorprietary frimwares to be more compatible with various computers. Easy to find in the doc and in the list of debian firmware packages. I found a list of all the firwares, listed inside a tar file, and then I installed them via apt-get. apt-get is superior to manual .deb files for the sake of automatic updates. I had the need of firmware-atheros, firmware-linux-non-free, and firmware-realtek. But I installed all of the others too.

Do not change the graphics drivers, keep nouveau as driver it is more stable and hardware independent.

the commands lsusb and lsusb -l show what speeds of USB sockets you have 10000M refers to USB3.1 5000M refers to USB3 400M refers to USB2.

possible extra tricks:

the debian installer pretends that --force-extra-removable will support buggy firmwares and bioses. So one can run grub-install --force-extra-removable and update-grub this and then run again the command grub-install --removable to have something clean on top.

I had once a broken bios booting on an auto-detected slot for booting. BOOTX64.efi was not bootable. But if I erased the same file name with the content of grub.efi, then it became bootable. It can fix certain biosses, but it is stil lpreferable to keep things as they are from the start.

you can see the source of grub2-common. This is what grub-install uses on debian apt source grub2-common I did not see a good ground for using --force-extra-removable so I do not use it. there are different forks of grub, do not be confused the doc of other grub versions.

If the bootloader is not visible in the bios, you need to try again. But you do not need to reinstall debian. You can fix this if you can boot on any linux. You probably need to fix the /etc/fstab. Do not confuse the fstab on the non-usb hard disc and the fstab on the usb.

How to use a chroot: apt-get install binutils debootstrap sudo mkdir -p /mnt/usb sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/usb cd /mnt/usb sudo mount -t proc proc proc/ sudo mount --rbind /sys sys/ sudo mount --rbind /dev dev/ sudo chroot /mnt/usb /bin/bash sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi

It makes the shell and grub think the root is at a special place.